# I tried to change the color of the status info, it does not work now

Tags: git, version-control

I tried to make colors a bit different while displaying status info, but I did manage to ruin something. When I type git status to see my unstaged files and stuff, the reply is :
fatal: bad numeric config value 'blue' for 'color.status' in C:/....=gitconfig: invalid unit
add and commit work still. How can i reset my settings? 
(I am new to git)
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Run `git config --global color.status always`. 
I think you accidentally set it to an invalid value.

Quoting the man page (readable in `man git-config` or [on the git-scm site](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)):

```
 color.status
   A boolean to enable/disable color in the output of git-status(1).
   May be set to always, false (or never) or auto (or true), in which
   case colors are used only when the output is to a terminal. 
   Defaults to false.
```

UPDATE:

Here are some examples to set the individual colors:

```
git config --global color.status.added magenta
git config --global color.status.changed blue
git config --global color.status.untracked yellow
```

And the docs for `color.status.<slot>`:

> Use customized color for status colorization.
>   `<slot>` is one of **header** (the header text of the status message),
>   **added** or **updated** (files which are added but not committed),
>   **changed** (files which are changed but not added in the index),
>   **untracked** (files which are not tracked by Git), 
>   **branch** (the current branch), 
>   or **nobranch** (the color the no branch warning is shown in, defaulting to red).

And info about the possible color values:

> The value for these configuration variables is a list of colors (at
>   most two) and attributes (at most one), separated by spaces. The
>   colors accepted are normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue,
>   magenta,cyan and white; the attributes are bold, dim, ul, blink and
>   reverse. The first color given is the foreground; the second is the
>   background. The position of the attribute, if any, doesn't matter.
>
> Colors (foreground and background) may also be given as numbers
>   between 0 and 255; these use ANSI 256-color mode (but note that not
>   all terminals may support this).