# fatal: bad numeric config value 'white' for 'color.status': invalid unit

Tags: git, config, git-bash

It worked when I tried `git init` and `git add` but it got an error with `git commit` (I'm haven't tried other commands).

The error message:

> fatal: bad numeric config value 'white' for 'color.status': invalid unit

I had done this:

```sh
git config --global color.status always
```

But I still get an error. I have tried in git-bash, Windows command prompt, and Commander.

Answer (score 3):

`git config --global` will modify your global Git settings, but you still might have a *local* setting which could overwrite it.

Check first your full setting:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config --show-origin -l
```

Then you can see if there is one with status set to an invalid value, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28093016/6309).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git config --global --edit
```

Then in the editor just change value of "status" to "auto" and save.

Answer (score 0):

The problem :
fatal: bad boolean config value 'green' for 'status.color'

this will really help you :

```
git config --global status.color "auto"
```